# css height is wrong when using percentage

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a generic alert element, that changes according to the parent div's height. At first, when I just designed everything, I used specific heights, but now I want to make it all relative, and for some reason those are calculated wrong!

so say this is my html:

```
<div class="alert">
    <span class="divider-vertical"></span>
</div>
```

and my css used to be:

```
.alert {
    height: 80px;
} 

.divider-vertical {
    height: 30px;
    margin: 25px 0; // 25*2 + 30 = 80
}
```

Now I wanted to turn this into relative percentages, so:

```
<div style="height: 80px;">
  <div class="alert">
    <span class="divider-vertical"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
.alert {
    height: 100%;
}

.divider-vertical {
    height: 37.5%;
    margin: 25px 0;
}
```

I used that figure based on the calculation: `100 * (30.0 / 80.0) = 37.5`. Now when I opened up chrome and checked to see the `computed` attributes, I found that `.alert` has a height of `80px` (as it should), **but `.divider-vertical` has only `29.25px`**. Why is that?

There's no other conflicting attribute somewhere else and the chrome dev tools assure me that the elements height is indeed 37.5%. Notice this isn't a case of some infinite decimal number, the calculation returns *exactly* 37.5% so why would there be any trouble here?

Comment: Are you accounting for borders/padding etc? Are you using the `box-sizing' property? JSfiddle would help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DLpYK/ it's 30px for me..

Comment: @Marcel thanks. For some reason when I tried to replicate it with jsfiddle it gave me `height: auto` instead of actual computed pixels

Comment: @yuvi show your replication? Is your span a `block` or anything similair that allows dimensions to be set?

Comment: @Paulie_D you're right. I'm using `box-sizing: border-box` and removing that through the chrome dev tools resolves the issue. Wow. Is there any solution that doesn't involve removing `border-box` (I want to leave it in if possible)

Comment: @Paulie_D I just read about `box-sizing` a bit (it was actually applied from an external css file I was using). I wasn't familiar with it, and it seems like 29.25px is actually a correction I probably want to keep (because it accounts for margins and borders and whatnot, and keeps everything consistent). So thank you for pointing me in the right direction, can you post an answer so I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that the `box-sizing: border-box` property is set in your CSS to account for borders/padding etc  thus causing some confusion?

That being the case you probably want to keep it so that everything is consistent.

Answer (score 2):

I you wnat to be able to set dimensions to your element, you should make it of the *block* family

for instance

```
.divider-vertical {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

will solve your issue

Comment: @Sigma thanks! Though eventually it seems the problem was not related to the element not being in the block family, but to the `box-sizing` attribute being used (see comment on original post)

Comment: FYI This article about box-sizing is worth mentioning: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: @Sigma I was guessing what was the problem, based on the code posted; Paulie_D had a better *instinct*. I should have noted that, if in the first code example the size was succesful, block display was somewhere. But this shows the convenience to publish the problem in a fiddle or similar ...